# ReactJS filterable, sortable tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

In my component's state there is a 'contributors' array. Each element of this array is an object with some properties. I want to display them in a table. And I want to have an ability to sort and filter it. So E.g.:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Contributions</th>
    <th>Followers</th>
    <th>Repos</th>
    <th>Gists</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>3000</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>George</td>
    <td>200</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Stephanie</td>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Caroline</td>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paul</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>9001</td>
    <td>33333</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The date is taken from the state which is taken from the API response.
I would like to have the ability to sort it alphabetically (a-z, z-a), and by each of the numbers (contributions, followers, repos, gists - biggest to smallest, smallest to biggest). And filter it by amount. I was looking for a library that does this for me but to no avail. How can I implement that?

Comment: I would look for a JavaScript function that does the classic a-b sorting and just use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [react-data-grid](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/)

Examples :

- Sort: http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/sortable-cols
- Filters: http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/filterable-grid

Comment: What if I want to filter numbers from-to, not just by string?

Comment: Custom filters: http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/examples.html#/custom-filters . Then maybe you can create you own filter component, not sure about that.